# how to put a button next to table using bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to set a button sit next to a table within a div.

my code is:

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">  <!-- main div -->
  <div> <!-- table div -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
      <thead><tr>
           <!-- 4 Header -->
      </tr></thead>
      <tbody> <tr><td>
            <!-- first row -->
      </td></tr></tbody>
     </table>
    </div> 
  <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="col-xs-2" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  name="search" id="search">Search</button>   
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  name="add" id="add">Add</button> 
  </div>   
</div>
```

-- main div close

what i am getting is:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is your expectation make a drawing on paint and share photo here so we can clearify you problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the main div to class: `col-xs-12`

and button `div` to `col-xs-8` or `col-xs-10`.

So, main is total 12 in which you are putting the Table with `*-xs-2` and button with `*-xs-8`

Try this

```
     <!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-xs-4"> 
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-xs-8">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-3" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  name="search" id="search">Search</button>   
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  name="add" id="add">Add</button>  
    </div>

  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/hbp71ejr/

Comment: tried.but it is showing big gap between table and buttons

Comment: added in answer refer that solution

Comment: Got It? @anupriya

Comment: still same.or else instead of this what i can use ?

Comment: add screenshot.

Comment: attached.see after 2button i have big space. and table size also reduced

Comment: As I can see you need to play with bootstrap classes. It will get resolve. There something also in your code that you haven't shared. Might be because of parent css causing this. You can see the link that I have provided in answer. Its showing correctly. As Question said you just need the a way to put the button next to table. That way I showed you. Play with classes. You will get the desired UI